# How to store the number form 9 different textbox and sort acceding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

This button is populate which means click on this button will auto generate random numbers .

This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rid = RandomNumber(-111, 999);
    int rid1 = RandomNumber(-111, 999);
    int rid2 = RandomNumber(-222, 888);
    int rid3 = RandomNumber(-333, 777);
    int rid4 = RandomNumber(-222, 777);
    int rid5 = RandomNumber(-333, 444);
    int rid6 = RandomNumber(-555, 888);
    int rid7 = RandomNumber(444, 999);
    int rid8 = RandomNumber(111, 222);
    int rid9 = RandomNumber(222, 333);

    txt1.Text = rid.ToString();
    txt2.Text = rid1.ToString();
    txt3.Text = rid3.ToString();
    txt4.Text = rid4.ToString();
    txt5.Text = rid5.ToString();
    txt6.Text = rid6.ToString();
    txt7.Text = rid7.ToString();
    txt8.Text = rid8.ToString();
    txt9.Text = rid9.ToString();
}
```

The second button is sort list.

How to take all the numbers and follow acceding to put back in the 9 different textbox ?

---

This is the coding for button sortlist:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int no1;
    int no2;
    int no3;
    int no4;
    int no5;
    int no6;
    int no7;
    int no8;
    int no9;
    //int answer;

    no1 = int.Parse(txt1.Text);
    no2 = int.Parse(txt2.Text);
    no3 = int.Parse(txt3.Text);
    no4 = int.Parse(txt4.Text);
    no5 = int.Parse(txt5.Text);
    no6 = int.Parse(txt6.Text);
    no7 = int.Parse(txt7.Text);
    no8 = int.Parse(txt8.Text);
    no9 = int.Parse(txt9.Text);


    int[] a = new int[] {no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8,no9 };

    Array.Sort(a);


    foreach (var str in a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
    }

}
```

I can display sort ACS in MessageBox but I can't put the number ACS into textbox
But still can't get the answer, where was wrong?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Group all the numbers to list and then use linq: linq.oderBy(i=>i);

Comment: Just to clarify - when you click `Button2`, you want to read the values from the textboxes 1-9, sort them into ascending order, and put them back into the textboxes in the new order?

Comment: protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @MartinParkin: Yes, how the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could throw the generated numbers into a list, sort the list and assign the numbers accordingly. Thus, `txt1.Text = sortedRandList[0];` and so on for the rest.

To get slightly cleaner code, you could consider also throwing all the text boxes within a list, and eventually end up doing `textBoxesList[i] = sortedRandList[i];`. That should clean up the code a little bit.

Comment: @ikramlim: `sortedRandList` is something you will need to create. You create the list, place the numbers you have generated in it and sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create List of ints and then sort it like this :

```
List<int> rids = null;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rids = new List<int>()
    {
       RandomNumber(-111, 999),
       RandomNumber(-111, 999),
       RandomNumber(-222, 888),
       RandomNumber(-333, 777),
       RandomNumber(-222, 777),
       RandomNumber(-333, 444),
       RandomNumber(-555, 888),
       RandomNumber(444, 999),
       RandomNumber(111, 222),
       RandomNumber(222, 333)
    };         

    DisplayValues();  // use it if you want to show your values in UI

}

protected void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   rids.Sort();

   DisplayValues()
}

private void DisplayValues()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
   {
       if (Controls[i] is TextBox) if(Controls[i]).ID.Contains("txt"))
       (Controls[i] as TextBox).Text = rids[Int32.Parse(Controls[i].ID.Replace("txt", "")) - 1].ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Updated. Now it works for me... http://i.gyazo.com/8d3058299cf58da55e9b95aeddc8a581.png

Comment: Thank you alot, but i have another error
- System.web.ui.control does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method Name accepting a first argument of type.....

Comment: can u share your full code to me? ikramlim@gmail.com 
Thank you friend.

Comment: i get this error http://i.gyazo.com/eb14e85fd695b25bb433dfbe6651bcb4.png
http://i.gyazo.com/5061bba6ff6de907c83ae190b2bd3db6.png

Comment: Oh lol.... It's for WEB and not Winforms or wpf... You should have mentioned this in your question... I'll try to update my code give me 5 mins

Comment: Opss sorry Sorry, i didnt mention. thats way i get error? sorry2

Comment: @ikramlim Please check again, i changed .Name property of Winforms to ID property of its Web Forms counterpart...

Comment: but i still have error in .Text 
-System.web.ui.control does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method Name accepting a first argument of type.....

Comment: Try to use `(Controls[i] as TextBox).Text` instead of  `Controls[i].TextBox`